# Iterating DataSet Tables

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I am running a paramterized SQL Stored Procedure that runs two select statements.  I want to assign a `DataSet()` to the returned result for easier processing.  However, in my syntax I get an error of

> Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Data.DataSet'

Can someone show me how to do what I am after here?  -- rather than refer to it as `ds.Tables[0];` I would like to associate a meaningful name.

```
public DataSet RunOneStoredProc()
{
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SQLCon))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetTeachersStudents", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@yearstart", SqlDbType.Date, 100);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@yearend", SqlDbType.Date, 100);
        cmd.Parameters["@yearstart"].Value = dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        cmd.Parameters["@yearend"].Value = dtpEndDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var ds = new DataSet();
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            da.Fill(ds);
        return dataset;
    }
}

private void btnPush_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataSet teachers = new DataSet();
    DataSet students = new DataSet();
    ds = RunOneStoredProc();
    teachers = ds.Tables[0];
    students = ds.Tables[1];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You are also creating a new instance of `DataSet ds`. It is not necessary since `RunOneStoredProc()` returns a new instance.

```
private void btnPush_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = RunOneStoredProc();
        DataTable teachers = ds.Tables[0];
        DataTable students = ds.Tables[1];

    }
```

Comment: If you don't want to use index to access the different tables in the data set, you can use names. `DataTable teachers = ds.Tables["teachers"];`

Comment: You said I am creating a new instance of ds.  Do you mean remove the DataSet ds decleration from RunOneStoredProc()?

Comment: You don't need to create another instance of DataSet `DataSet ds = new DataSet();` Because `RunOneStoredProc()` already returns a new instance.

Comment: `DataSet ds = RunOneStoredProc();` is all you need.